# Reducing useless subdivisions

Tags: subdivision-surface

How would it be possible to stop certain parts of a model being subdivided where its not needed?

[image]

This picture shows how it currently does it, notice the lines in between the sharps? it adds useless polygons, and can be manually removed but takes a long time to do the whole model.

[image]

Is there anyway to get this result without effecting the rest of the model or doing it manually ?

Comment: It's a matter of changing your over-all approach. Only add as many polygons as you absolutely need to begin with. Sometimes adding loop cuts or subdividing only certain selected edges or faces is better than using a SubSurf Modifier. If you end up with extra edge loops you can press X and Dissolve them.

Comment: Thanks il keep that in mind for the future, and the dissolve function fixes all my current problems :)

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it was a solution for you! I will go ahead and post my comment as an answer so that this question can be listed as answered. Please consider accepting the answer if you feel it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of changing your over-all approach.

1. Only add as many polygons as you absolutely need to begin with.
2. Sometimes adding loop cuts or subdividing only certain selected edges or faces is better than using a SubSurf Modifier.
3. If you end up with extra edge loops you can press X and Dissolve them.